# How can i adjust width of the entire table and of columns using tabular package?

Tags: tables, tabularx

I tried using tabular package to make the rigth column wider in respect to the left (that should be 1/3 approximately). In my code something is wrong because it gives the left wider and the total width is more than the text width. Any helps?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Figures/} }

\usepackage[%
style=apa, backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

%eli
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{P}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\captionsetup{
    justification = centering
}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
    \centering{\scriptsize
        \begin{tabular}{lm{0.3\textwidth}p{0.1\textwidth}}
            \hline
            Author  &Test Procedure \\ \hline
            Deere DU, Miller RP (\cite{deere1966engineering})& Record three readings along the length of NX-size core for each 451 rotation. Average a total of 24 readings,
            disregarding the erroneous readings.\\ \hline
            Young RP, Fowell RJ (\cite{young1978assessing})& Divide rock mass surface into grids and average the single impacts from each grid.\\ \hline
            ISRM (\cite{international1976engineering})& Record 20 rebound values from single impacts separated by at least a plunger diameter, and average the upper
            10 values.\\ \hline
            Goktan RM, Ayday C(\cite{goktan1993suggested})& Record 20 rebound values from single impacts separated by at least a plunger diameter. Reject outlier values by using Chauvenet’s criterion, and average the remaining readings.\\ \hline
            Soiltest & Record 15 rebound values from single impacts and average the highest 10. The maximum deviation from the
            mean should be less than 2.5.\\ \hline
            Matthews JA, Shakesby RA (\cite{matthews1984status})& 15 measurements on any sample. The mean of the rebound values are calculated and the five values deviating
            most from the mean are discarded.\\ \hline
            Kazi A, Al-Mansour ZR (\cite{kazi1980empirical}) & Record at least 35 rebound readings, drop the 10 lowest readings and average the remaining 25.\\ \hline
            Katz O. et al. (\cite{kazi1980empirical}) & Perform 32–40 individual impacts and average the upper $50\%$. \\ \hline
            Poole RW, Farmer IW (\cite{poole1980consistency}) & Select the peak rebound value from five continuous impacts at a point. Average the peaks of the three sets of
            tests conducted at three separated points. \\ \hline
            Hucka V (\cite{hucka1965rapid}) & Select the peak rebound value from 10 continuous impacts at a point. Average the peaks of the three sets of
            tests conducted at three separated points. \\ \hline
            GBG [41]& Record 12 readings taken in a diamond pattern at the test point. Discard the lowest and highest values to
            obtain a mean rebound number.\\ \hline
            USBR [43]& Ten readings at various locations on each surface. Discount the five lowest readings, and average the highest five.\\ \hline
            Sumner P and Nel W (\cite{sumner2002effect})& Take 15 readings at different points and discard five great outliers to obtain a mean value from the remaining 10 values.\\   
            \hline  
    \end{tabular}}
    \caption{Some recommended Schmidt hammer test procedures (from \cite{goktan2005comparative})}.
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{lm{0.3\textwidth}p{0.1\textwidth}}` contains three column, but your table only seems to use two of them. Probably you wanted something similar to `\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.25\textwidth}p{0.7\textwidth}}` or `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}`?

Comment: Completely unrelated to the actual issue, but I'd suggest that you replace the `\hline`  commands by `\torule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` from the `booktabs` package. The latter have some vertical white space around them and make the table look less cramped. In addition to that, I'd use a larger font size than `scriptsize`. I'd also suggest to replace `(\cite{...})`  with `\parencite{...}` as the latter automatically adds the parentheses around the citations.

Comment: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize\raggedright\arraybackslash}X>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X}` might also be an alternative.

Comment: Lastly, could you please add the **relevant** contents of the `.bib` file. (See also: [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)) Useful suggestions on how you can improve the table layout are quite hard to give if the citations in your table are not printed correctly. (As I don't have your bib file available, I only get the citation key printed in the table.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set the table as a [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable), which break across pages. Then, you can set the table in normal `fontsize`, and with the the same spacing as the surrounding text -- unless you want the tabular to be distinctly different from the surrounding text. Then, you should chose two grades smaller font that `normalfont`.

Since you have a simple table structure, you can easily calculate the column width using `\dimexpr`. You do not need [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx)' advance calculation algorithms. Since I removed one `\tabcolsep` from the each columns using `@{}`, only one additional `tabcolsep` has to be subtracted from each column. I define two new column types, `F` and `L`, 1/3 and 2/3 text width, respectively. I have typeset the second column justified and use [microtype](https://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) to have better line breaks.

If you prefer [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) type columns, I recommend [xltabular](https://ctan.org/pkg/xltabular), which is a drop in replacement for [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable). It offers `X` columns in addition to breaking long tables at the bottom margin. (It is so compatible, that you only need to change three line of code from `longtable` to `xltabular`. Then you changed the commenting on the `%\newcolumntype`definition, uncomment the definition of `F` and `L` that are commented, and comment those two that are not commented.)

I also added some space between the rows instead of horizontal rules, because I find such space less disruptive (personal taste).

[image][image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[%
style=apa, backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{array, xltabular}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0.5em}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}

%\newcolumntype{F}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=0.5\hsize}X} % First column (ragged right)
%\newcolumntype{L}{>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X}                                                  % Last column (justified)


\newcolumntype{F}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr((0.333\textwidth)-\tabcolsep)}} % First column (ragged right)
\newcolumntype{L}{p{\dimexpr((0.667\textwidth)-\tabcolsep)}}                     % Last column (justified)

\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
\begin{singlespacing}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} FL @{}}
\caption{Some recommended Schmidt hammer test procedures (from Goktan2005)}\\
\toprule
Author  &Test Procedure \\ \midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
Author  &Test Procedure \\ \midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{r@{}}{\small Continues\ldots}\\
\endfoot
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\ldots\ \small Continued}\\
\endlastfoot

Deere DU, Miller RP (Deere1966)& Record three readings along the length of NX-size core for each 451 rotation. Average a total of 24 readings, disregarding the erroneous readings.\\\addlinespace[6pt] 
            Young RP, Fowell RJ (Young1978)& Divide rock mass surface into grids and average the single impacts from each grid.\\
\addlinespace[6pt] 
            ISRM (International1976)& Record 20 rebound values from single impacts separated by at least a plunger diameter, and average the upper 10 values.\\ \addlinespace[6pt]  
            Goktan RM, Ayday C (Goktan1993)& Record 20 rebound values from single impacts separated by at least a plunger diameter. Reject outlier values by using Chauvenet’s criterion, and average the remaining readings.\\
\addlinespace[6pt]  
            Soiltest & Record 15 rebound values from single impacts and average the highest 10. The maximum deviation from the mean should be less than 2.5.\\
\addlinespace[6pt]
            Matthews JA, Shakesby RA (Matthews1984)& 15 measurements on any sample. The mean of the rebound values are calculated and the five values deviating most from the mean are discarded.\\
\addlinespace[6pt]  
            Kazi A, Al-Mansour ZR (Kazi1980) & Record at least 35 rebound readings, drop the 10 lowest readings and average the remaining 25.\\
\addlinespace[6pt]  
            Katz O. et al. (Kazi1980b) & Perform 32–40 individual impacts and average the upper $50\%$. \\ \addlinespace[6pt]  
            Poole RW, Farmer IW (Poole1980) & Select the peak rebound value from five continuous impacts at a point. Average the peaks of the three sets of tests conducted at three separated points. \\
\addlinespace[6pt]  
            Hucka V (Hucka1965) & Select the peak rebound value from 10 continuous impacts at a point. Average the peaks of the three sets of tests conducted at three separated points. \\
\addlinespace[6pt]  
            GBG [41]& Record 12 readings taken in a diamond pattern at the test point. Discard the lowest and highest values to obtain a mean rebound number.\\
\addlinespace[6pt]  
            USBR [43]& Ten readings at various locations on each surface. Discount the five lowest readings, and average the highest five.\\
\addlinespace[6pt]  
            Sumner P and Nel W (Sumner\&Nel2002)& Take 15 readings at different points and discard five great outliers to obtain a mean value from the remaining 10 values.\\
\addlinespace[6pt]
\end{xltabular}
\end{singlespacing}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're looking to use the `\tabularx` package and its eponymous environment. The following solution employs the following ideas:

- Set the overall width to `\textwidth`; use `X` as the column type for both columns; and make the third column three times as wide as the first. (When creating several X-type columns with differing widths, be sure to make the sum of the widths equal to the number of X-type columns. In the code below, we have 0.5+1.5=2=# of X-type columns.) Aside: I came up with the 1:3 ratio of relative column width by trial and error.
- Change the (relative) font size from `\scriptsize` to `\small` -- your readers will appreciate the gesture
- Give the table a much more open "look", by using fewer but well-spaced horizontal lines. Remember that whitespace can be every bit as effective as a line in conveying a sense of visual separation.

### [image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Figures/} }
%
%% not needed for this example:
%\usepackage[%
%style=apa, backend=biber
%]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{float,lipsum,subfig}
\usepackage{adjustbox,tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry,booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools,array,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt  % '2pt' is not exactly much

\usepackage[justification = centering]{caption}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
    % \centering % redundant
    %\scriptsize % barely legible
    \small

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L{0.5} L{1.5} @{}}
    \toprule
    Author & Test Procedure \\ 
    \midrule
    Deere DU, Miller RP (\cite{deere1966engineering})
    & Record three readings along the length of NX-size core for each 451 rotation. Average a total of 24 readings, disregarding the erroneous readings.\\ \addlinespace
    Young RP, Fowell RJ (\cite{young1978assessing})
    & Divide rock mass surface into grids and average the single impacts from each grid.\\ \addlinespace
    ISRM (\cite{international1976engineering})
    & Record 20 rebound values from single impacts separated by at least a plunger diameter, and average the upper 10 values.\\ \addlinespace
    Goktan RM, Ayday C (\cite{goktan1993suggested})
    & Record 20 rebound values from single impacts separated by at least a plunger diameter. Reject outlier values by using Chauvenet's criterion, and average the remaining readings.\\ \addlinespace
    Soiltest 
    & Record 15 rebound values from single impacts and average the highest 10. The maximum deviation from the
    mean should be less than 2.5.\\ \addlinespace
    Matthews JA, Shakesby RA (\cite{matthews1984status})
    & 15 measurements on any sample. The mean of the rebound values are calculated and the five values deviating most from the mean are discarded.\\ \addlinespace
    Kazi A, Al-Mansour ZR (\cite{kazi1980empirical}) 
    & Record at least 35 rebound readings, drop the 10 lowest readings and average the remaining 25.\\ \addlinespace
    Katz O. et al. (\cite{kazi1980empirical}) 
    & Perform 32--40 individual impacts and average the upper $50\%$. \\ \addlinespace
    Poole RW, Farmer IW (\cite{poole1980consistency}) 
    & Select the peak rebound value from five continuous impacts at a point. Average the peaks of the three sets of tests conducted at three separated points. \\ \addlinespace
    Hucka V (\cite{hucka1965rapid}) 
    & Select the peak rebound value from 10 continuous impacts at a point. Average the peaks of the three sets of tests conducted at three separated points. \\ \addlinespace
    GBG [41]
    & Record 12 readings taken in a diamond pattern at the test point. Discard the lowest and highest values to obtain a mean rebound number.\\ \addlinespace
    USBR [43]
    & Ten readings at various locations on each surface. Discount the five lowest readings, and average the highest five.\\ \addlinespace
    Sumner P and Nel W (\cite{sumner2002effect})
    & Take 15 readings at different points and discard five great outliers to obtain a mean value from the remaining 10 values.\\   
    \bottomrule  
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Some recommended Schmidt hammer test 
    procedures (from \cite{goktan2005comparative})}.
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wonder whether a preamble like  `{@{}lX@{}}` wouldn't look a bit nicer (supposing the real \cites would be numeric)?

Comment: @Bernard: I agree. However, from the use of `style=apa` in combination with `(\cite{...}]` I'd guess that the citations in the table are in fact *not* numeric. However, the use of `[43]` in some cels seems to contradict.

Comment: @Bernard - Funny you should ask. I actually started with `lX`; as that is what the OP appears to have done too. But I then realized that by allowing some line breaks in the first column, I could make the second column quite a bit wider. This, in turn, allows increasing the relative font size noticeably without the table becoming taller than `\textheight`. It was a case of having to make a trade-off between two coflicting aesthetic criteria; for me at least, the gain of being able to use `\small` instead of `\scriptsize` outweighed the cost of introducing some linebreaks in the first column.

Comment: @leandriis -- Yeah, I couldn't figure out either whether the OP intends to have numeric-style or authoryear-style citation call-outs. If it's the latter, then permitting line breaks in the first column will be essential.

Comment: @Mico: I didn't think of this aspect of page breaking. Probably you're right – I didn't test anything myself. There's also the possibility to use the `adjustwidth` environment if it's for a minor adjustment, though.

Comment: @Mico thank you for this so clear reply. There is only a problem, running your code the table is longer than the page. I attached a figure in my question.

Comment: @Elisam - Judging by the screenshot you posted, you seem to have increased linespacing in your document; that's not something disclosed in the sample code you posted. Please advise if my impression is correct. Separately, do you get a better result if you change `L{0.5} L{1.5}` to `L{0.45} L{1.55}` or even `L{0.4} L{1.6}`?

Comment: @Bernard sorry, you see number in brackets for citations but it's onlt for me to remind to insert them, cause some are not available in biblatex and i'm trying to avoid this problem. i'm using apa style for referencing.

Comment: @Mico that's rigth, i have 1.5 and i should use 1.5 for the text. I tried reducing to 1 and all the tables were within the page. The best think could be use 1.5 for the text and 1 for the table. Is that possible?

Comment: @Elisam - Please advise as to *how* you increase and decrease line-spacing at present. (There are several possible methods, so it's important to know which method you use.)

Comment: @Mico yes sorry. `\linespread{1.5}\selectfont`

Comment: @Elisam - Manipulating the low-level command `\linespread` is **not recommended**. I suggest you load the `setspace` package and issue the command `\setstretch{1.5}` in the preamble. That way, line-spacing in `table` and `figure` environments as well as in footnotes will stay at 1.0, i.e., single-spacing, automatically.

Comment: @Elisam - Incidentally, it would have been really helpful if you had disclosed in your sample code that you run `\linespread{1.5}`; a lot of subsequent back-and-forth could have been avoided.

Comment: @Mico perfect, it works! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @leandriis thank you for your helpful suggestions!