# How to set row distance and width of a table using longtable package?

Tags: tables, longtable

I want to create a table using `\longtable` package. I tried this way:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{float,lipsum,subfig,booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools,array,dcolumn,longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|*4{p{2cm}|}}
        \toprule
        low threshold (\%)& L mean&  R mean observed & R mean predicted\\ 
        \hline
        85 &188.2   &10.0   &\textbf{8.6} \\
        80 &375.3   &10.5   &\textbf{20} \\
        75 &326.2   &23.4   &\textbf{19.1} \\
        40 &247.1   &15.6   &\textbf{14.3} \\
        30 &215.1   &18.2   &\textbf{11.5} \\
        25 &258.9   &16.0   &\textbf{15.2} \\
        20 &243.8   &16.9   &\textbf{14.1} \\
        20 &264.0   &11.8   &\textbf{15.6} \\
        10 &285.4   &17.6   &\textbf{16.5} \\
        10 &295.7   &19.3   &\textbf{17.1} \\
        5 &239.9    &14.7   &\textbf{13.9}\\
        5 &281.3    &23.3   &\textbf{16.3}\\
        0 &780.0    &49.1 &\textbf{50.6}\\
        0 &264  &11.8   &\textbf{15.6}\\
        0 &285.8    &17.6   &\textbf{16.5}\\
        0 &295.7    &19.3   &\textbf{17.1}\\
        0 &239.9    &14.7   &\textbf{13.9}\\
        0   &296.9  &18.4   &\textbf{17.4}\\
        0   &304.8  &21.1   &\textbf{18.0}\\
        0   &321.9  &21.6   &\textbf{19.1}\\
        0   &375.6  &27.1   &\textbf{20.3}\\
        0   &413.0  &21.1   &\textbf{21.4}\\
        0   &444.9  &18.4   &\textbf{22.8}\\
        0   &449.1  &34.3   &\textbf{23.3}\\
        0   &484.7  &34.3   &\textbf{25.3}\\
        0   &489.3  &33.9   &\textbf{25.3}\\
        0   &505.8  &21.1   &\textbf{26.4}\\
        0   &542.1  &41.9   &\textbf{28.3}\\
        0   &563.9  &34.3   &\textbf{29.8}\\
        0   &572.4  &34.3   &\textbf{30.3}\\
        0   &646.2  &34.3   &\textbf{35.7}\\
        0   &662.2  &41.9   &\textbf{36.9}\\
        0   &538.8  &23.1   &\textbf{28.7}\\
        0   &466.3  &18.2   &\textbf{24.2}\\
        0   &377.9  &12.7   &\textbf{20.4}\\
        0   &636.7  &32.6   &\textbf{35.2}\\
        0   &691.2  &38.4   &\textbf{38.6}\\
        0   &766.8  &48.6   &\textbf{43.3}\\
        0   &614.5  &24.3   &\textbf{33.6}\\
        0   &543.7  &23.0   &\textbf{29.0}\\
        0   &499.8  &16.5   &\textbf{25.9}\\
        0   &710.3  &35.1   &\textbf{38.8}\\
        0   &774.0  &50.5   &\textbf{48.5}\\
        0   &780.0  &49.1   &\textbf{50.6}\\
        0   &761.3  &49.5   &\textbf{41.1}\\
        0   &762.9  &50.1   &\textbf{41.4}\\
        0   &767.0  &50.3   &\textbf{43.4}\\
        0   &588.1  &35.0   &\textbf{31.4}\\
        0   &601.7  &38.7   &\textbf{32.6}\\
        0   &423.9  &11.3   &\textbf{21.9}\\
        0   &425.3  &10.5   &\textbf{22.2}\\
        0   &623.7  &29.9   &\textbf{33.7}\\
        \bottomrule
        \caption{}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I want to set the width of the table to the text width and i also want to make its layout less ugly :D at the moment there is too much space between raws. 
Any suggestion?

[image: last layout of longtable after @Zarko suggestions]

Comment: Please make your document example compilable. Also make it minimal (remove all what is not related to table.

Comment: @Zarko i think now it's ok

Comment: To make your code compilable, the `booktabs` package is missing. Also, remove the `&` after `R mean predicted`.

Comment: Do you test your code? It still have errors :-(. you removed to much packages, have wrong numbers of ampersands in the first table row, Repairing this, now rows in table is tight together ...

Comment: Could the large distances between row be related to you changing the linespacing as discussed in the comments to your preivious question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506464/how-can-i-adjust-width-of-the-entire-table-and-of-columns-using-tabular-package#comment1279592_506467 If so, please add this information to your question.

Comment: Please also don not use vertical lines in combination with horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package as they are incompatible (see the small gap in the vertical line around the intersections with the horizontal lines). I'd also recommend to use the `siunitx` package for improved alignment of numbers. I'd also suggest to not try to make the table as wide as the textwidth as this will artificially increase the horizontal space between the columns.

Comment: Lastly, you might want to reconsider the use of bold numbers in all rows of the last column. Bold might be useful to highlight a few entries of a whole table. In your example, there are so many bold entries, that this is somehow distracting.

Comment: Your table with with of `\textwidth` will look very ugly ... Try `\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|*{4}{p{3cm}|}}
        \toprule
low threshold (\%)& L mean&  R mean observed & R mean predicted \\
        \hline
        85 &188.2   &10.0   &\textbf{8.6} \\
        80 &375.3   &10.5   &\textbf{20} \\
        \hline
        \bottomrule
        \caption{}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}`

Comment: I'd suggest the following: `\begin{longtable}{cccc}
        \toprule
        low threshold (\%)& L mean&  \multicolumn{2}{c}{R mean}\\
        \cmidrule{3-4}
        & &  observed &  predicted \\ 
        \midrule`

Comment: @leandriis thanks, i inserted bold numbers manually cause i want to highligth them in the discussion of the table. ok, so let's leave this table width, i should remove all the `\hline` rigth?

Comment: @leandriis i really like this layout, it's clear. Thank you very very much!

Comment: @Zarko really thanks, that's what i figured out. Thanks to you guys i now have an idea of different methods to create this kind of table. Thank you!!! Grazie mille!

Comment: @leandriis i'm sorry, if i run the code using the spacing `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}` here in this table i have too much spacing. As you told me before here we are not in a `\table` environment so the spacing for the tables are not 1 but 1.5 like specified. How can i avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibilities to design your table is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable}

\usepackage{siunitx} % <-- new
\usepackage{etoolbox}% <-- new
\newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}


%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\singlespacing  % <---
\begin{longtable}{S[table-format=2.0]
             *{2}{S[table-format=2.1]}
                  S[table-format=2.1,detect-weight]
                 }
\caption{Caption should be here}
\label{tab:mylongtable} \\
    \toprule
{low threshold (\%)} 
    & {L mean }& {R mean observed} & {R mean predicted} \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Caption should be here (cont.)}              \\
    \toprule
{low threshold (\%)}
    & {L mean }& {R mean observed} & {R mean predicted} \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{4}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Contionued on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
85 &188.2   &10.0   &\B    8.6           \\
80 &375.3   &10.5   &20     \\
75 &326.2   &23.4   &19.1 \\
40 &247.1   &15.6   &14.3 \\
30 &215.1   &18.2   &11.5 \\
25 &258.9   &16.0   &15.2 \\
20 &243.8   &16.9   &14.1 \\
20 &264.0   &11.8   &15.6 \\
10 &285.4   &17.6   &16.5 \\
10 &295.7   &19.3   &17.1 \\
5  &239.9   &14.7   &13.9 \\
5  &281.3   &23.3   &16.3 \\
0  &780.0   &49.1   &\B    50.6 \\
0  &264     &11.8   &15.6 \\
0  &285.8   &17.6   &16.5 \\
0  &295.7   &19.3   &17.1 \\
0  &239.9   &14.7   &13.9 \\
0  &296.9   &18.4   &17.4 \\
0  &304.8   &21.1   &18.0 \\
0  &321.9   &21.6   &19.1 \\
0  &375.6   &27.1   &20.3 \\
0  &413.0   &21.1   &21.4 \\
0  &444.9   &18.4   &22.8 \\
0  &449.1   &34.3   &23.3 \\
0  &484.7   &34.3   &25.3 \\
0  &489.3   &33.9   &25.3 \\
0  &505.8   &21.1   &26.4 \\
0  &542.1   &41.9   &28.3 \\
0  &563.9   &34.3   &29.8 \\
0  &572.4   &34.3   &30.3 \\
0  &646.2   &34.3   &35.7 \\
0  &662.2   &41.9   &36.9 \\
0  &538.8   &23.1   &28.7 \\
0  &466.3   &18.2   &24.2 \\
0  &377.9   &12.7   &20.4 \\
0  &636.7   &32.6   &35.2 \\
0  &691.2   &38.4   &38.6 \\
0  &766.8   &48.6   &43.3 \\
0  &614.5   &24.3   &33.6 \\
0  &543.7   &23.0   &29.0 \\
0  &499.8   &16.5   &25.9 \\
0  &710.3   &35.1   &38.8 \\
0  &774.0   &50.5   &48.5 \\
0  &780.0   &49.1   &50.6 \\
0  &761.3   &49.5   &41.1 \\
0  &762.9   &50.1   &41.4 \\
0  &767.0   &50.3   &43.4 \\
0  &588.1   &35.0   &31.4 \\
0  &601.7   &38.7   &32.6 \\
0  &423.9   &11.3   &21.9 \\
0  &425.3   &10.5   &22.2 \\
0  &623.7   &29.9   &33.7 \\
\end{longtable}
\onehalfspacing % <---
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

which produce the following table:

[image]

[image]

(red lines indicate pagelayout)

Comment: i edited my question to show you how i see my table cause of `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}` and `\setstretch{1.5}` in the preamble. I need them cause i must set 1.5 for the interline in my thesis. This cause also an interline of 1.5 also in the longtable. How can i do? @Zarko

Comment: @Elisam ,see edited answer ...

Comment: now it is perfect!!! thank you!!!

Comment: @Elisam, if my answer is perfect, then you can up-vote it or even accept :-)